# jquery google feed plugin w/ no output

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-feed-api

I am using the [JQuery Google Feed plugin (gFeed)](http://jquery.malsup.com/gfeed/) to output an RSS feed. I've successfully used this alternative before, but unfortunately I've stumbled into a bit of a problem. The RSS feed refuses to output into the specified div. I have confirmed the feed  https://www.phpbb.com/community/feed.php?mode=news displays correctly with Google Reader..

My site is `http://removed/index` and I also consulted the [Google Feed API developers page][3].

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<!-- include this plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.gfeed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


 // when the DOM is ready, convert the feed anchors into feed content
  $(document).ready(function() {
   // add a feed manually
    $('#feeds').gFeed({ 
       url: 'https://www.phpbb.com/community/feed.php?mode=news',
         title: 'A List Apart Feed (Added by Brute Force)'
     });    
    });
    </script>

     <div id="feeds">

     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JQuery gFeed plugin is quite old (2007) and it uses FeedControl which I believe was deprecated by Google.

I would recommend using the [jquery-feeds plugin](https://github.com/camagu/jquery-feeds), and then using code like:

```
$('#feeds').feeds({
    feeds: {
        feed1: 'https://www.phpbb.com/community/feed.php?mode=news'
    }
});​
```

[Fiddle here with a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/XmY9d/1/).

Comment: Thanks for the update..Will definitely bookmark that one. Once again another conundrum i placed myself in. Turns out i placed the jquery.feeds.min before the jquery.js. Switched the order around and viola.